# Gsap text animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

I am trying to build an animated slider using gsap and I am a beginner on gsap.

I need animation out on text when slide to next and animation in when the new slide comes.

Can anyone please help me with this?

If not understand my issue then let me know I will give you an example of what I actually want in the slider.

```js
console.clear(); // Just for codepen clear the console between refreshes
// gsap.registerPlugin(SplitText, Draggable);
document.querySelectorAll(".slider").forEach((container) => {
    // Setup variables
    const items = container.querySelectorAll(".slider__wrraper"),
        itemsMax = items.length - 1;
    const next = container.querySelector(".next"),
        prev = container.querySelector(".prev"),
        dots = container.querySelector(".slider_dots");
    let index = 0;
    const move = 100;
    const timer = 5000;
    const duration = 0.5;
    // let autoplay;
    //--------------------------------//
    //  Inital setup
    //--------------------------------//
    function init() {
        // Create  Dots
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            const dot = document.createElement("li");
            if (index === 0) dot.classList.add("active"); // Set the first dot to active
            // Allow clicking the dots
            dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
                slideLogic(false, index);
            });

            if (dots) dots.appendChild(dot);
        });
        // Animate the first element in
        gsap.set(items, { autoAlpha: 0 });
        gsap.set([".slider", items[index]], { autoAlpha: 1 });
        gsap.from(items[index], { autoAlpha: 0, x: move });
        // autoplay = window.setTimeout(slideLogic, timer);
    }
    // Run inital setup
    init();
    // END  Inital setup --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // ☝️ Touch
    //--------------------------------//
    if (window.Draggable) {
        Draggable.create(items, {
            type: "x", // Drag only on the X axis
            zIndexBoost: false,
            onDragStart: function () {
                // window.clearTimeout(autoplay); // disable autoplay
                slideLogic(this.getDirection() === "right" ? true : false);
            }
        });
    }
    // END ☝️ Touch  --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // Set active  dot
    //--------------------------------//
    function dotActive(index) {
        const dotsAll = dots.querySelectorAll("li");
        dotsAll.forEach((dot) => {
            dot.classList.remove("active");
        });
        dotsAll[index].classList.add("active");
    }
    // END Set active  dot --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // ️ Slide animation
    //--------------------------------//
    function slideAnimation(index, moveIn, outIn) {
        // Reset the properties you are animating below
        // Ohter wise they animate from that positon (probalby not visable)
        gsap.set(items, { xPercent: 0, scale: 1 });
        gsap.set(items[moveIn], { autoAlpha: 1 });

        // The animation
        const tl = gsap.timeline({
            defaults: {
                duration: duration
            },
            onStart: animationStart,
            onComplete: animationDone,
        });
        // Move out slide
        tl.to(items[index], { xPercent: outIn[0] });
        // move in slide
        tl.from(items[moveIn], { xPercent: outIn[1] }, "<");
        // Animate text
        tl.set(items[index], { autoAlpha: 0 }); // Hide moved out slide
    }
    function animationStart() {
        container.classList.add("running");
    }
    function animationDone() {
        toggleButtons();
        // autoplay = window.setTimeout(slideLogic, timer);
        container.classList.remove("running");
        gsap.set(items, { x: 0 });
    }
    // END ️ Slide animation --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // Slider ️ logic
    //--------------------------------//
    function slideLogic(prev, customMoveIn) {
        toggleButtons(); // Disable buttons
        // window.clearTimeout(autoplay); // disable autoplay
        let outIn = [-move, move];
        if (prev) outIn.reverse();
        let moveIn;
        // Check if moveIn is passed with the function
        if (typeof customMoveIn === "undefined") {
            if (prev) {
                moveIn = index === 0 ? itemsMax : index - 1;
            } else {
                moveIn = index === itemsMax ? 0 : index + 1;
            }
        } else {
            moveIn = customMoveIn;
        }
        if (dots) dotActive(moveIn); // Set active dot
        slideAnimation(index, moveIn, outIn); // Animation function
        // Changing the next index
        if (typeof customMoveIn === "undefined") {
            if (prev) {
                index === 0 ? (index = itemsMax) : index--;
            } else {
                index === itemsMax ? (index = 0) : index++;
            }
        } else {
            index === itemsMax ? (index = 0) : (index = customMoveIn++);
        }
    }
    // END Slider ️ logic --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // Button ️ control
    //--------------------------------//
    function toggleButtons() {
        if (next) next.disabled = !next.disabled;
        if (prev) prev.disabled = !prev.disabled;
    }
    if (next) next.addEventListener("click", () => slideLogic());
    if (prev) prev.addEventListener("click", () => slideLogic(true));
    // END Button ️ control --------------//
});
```

```css
.home-slider { overflow: hidden; }
.home-slider .slider { width: 100%; position: relative; }
.home-slider .slider .inner-container{ position: relative; height: 100vh; }
.home-slider .slider__wrraper { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.home-slider .slider__content_wrap .slider__img{ width: 406px; }
.home-slider .slider__content_wrap .slider__context{ width: calc(100% - 406px); padding-left: 70px; }
.home-slider .bgColor { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1; }
.home-slider .bgColor + .bgColor{ transform: translateX(100%); }
.home-slider .slider__btns button{ cursor: pointer; border: 0; background-color: transparent; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); }
.home-slider .slider__btns button.prev{ left: 30px; }
.home-slider .slider__btns button.next{ right: 30px; }
.home-slider .slider_dots > div{ width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<section class="home-slider">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <div class="slider__wrraper" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">
                        <div class="slider__content">
                            <div class="slider__content_wrap d-flex d-flex-wrap">
                                <div class="slider__img">
                                    <img src="assets/images/banner-slider.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slider__context">
                                    <h5>Welcome.</h5>
                                    <h2 class="slider__category">Test Title Goes Here</h2>
                                    <div class="text">Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, </div>
                                    <div class="btnwrap"><a href="#" title="" class="btnStyle">Let’s Connect<span></span></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider__wrraper" style="background-color: red;">
                        <div class="slider__content">
                            <div class="slider__content_wrap d-flex d-flex-wrap">
                                <div class="slider__img">
                                    <img src="assets/images/banner-slider.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slider__context">
                                    <h5>Welcome.</h5>
                                    <h2 class="slider__category">Test Title Goes Here</h2>
                                    <div class="text">Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, </div>
                                    <div class="btnwrap"><a href="#" title="" class="btnStyle">Let’s Connect<span></span></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider__wrraper" style="background-color: blue;">
                        <div class="slider__content">
                            <div class="slider__content_wrap d-flex d-flex-wrap">
                                <div class="slider__img">
                                    <img src="assets/images/banner-slider.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slider__context">
                                    <h5>Welcome.</h5>
                                    <h2 class="slider__category">Test Title Goes Here</h2>
                                    <div class="text">Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here, Test text goes here,</div>
                                    <div class="btnwrap"><a href="#" title="" class="btnStyle">Let’s Connect<span></span></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider_dots d-flex d-flex-wrap flex-justify-center">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__btns">
                        <button data-type="prev"class="slider__btn-switch prev"><div class="btn_text"><h5>Prev</h5><p>text text goes here</p></div></button>
                        <button data-type="next"class="slider__btn-switch next"><div class="btn_text"><h5>Next</h5><p>text text goes here</p></div></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Here you can check which type of animation I am looking for .https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/eYKvmYe

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).